# PHP: Use outside variable in static function in class

Tags: php, static

I would like to use a values stored in a seperate file in a static function in a PHP class.

Example:

```
<?php
include "vars.php";

class MyClass {
  public static function doSomething() {
    echo "Default value is ".$default_value;
  }
}

MyClass::doSomething();
?>
```

And in vars.php

```
<?php
$default_value = "DEFAULT";
?>
```

I get following error:
Notice: Undefined variable: default_value in C:\xampp\htdocs\mediamanager\new_hp\MyClass.php on line 6
Default value is

How would this be possible? Or is there a better way to read configuration values from a seperate file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare `$default` as a global variable using the `global` keyword, or put it into the `GLOBALS` superglobal.

Ps: For configuration, I would personally use a class, with constant members.

Comment: This is a typo. The issue consists also with the changed var name. I edited the original post. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Making it global does not work 'global $default_value;' does not get rid of the error.